# Bootstrap : Click tr to show a modal in except some td

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I have table list and when click `tr` the modal shows.

Is it possible to make the modal **not** to be shown when a `td` has `class="except"`

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/yF45N/2422/) is what I just tried so far

Comment: Please show us your own attempt on creating this yourself next time, http://jsfiddle.net/yF45N/2424/

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen  OK, Thank you very helpful